# Sistema de Búsqueda no encuentra el texto si tiene tildes

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy implementado un sistema de **búsqueda** a mi sitio web sin ajax, directamente a un archivo **busqueda.php** pero me doy cuenta que si el texto contiene tildes no hace match, si por ejemplo escribo "politica" no encuentra un titulo que tenga la palabra "política" escrito correctamente también el sistema de búsqueda funciona defectuoso si lo hago con **GET** al escribir "politica" me arroja todo lo que hay en la tabla sin hacer match así que tuve que hacerlo con **POST**. Aquí un pequeño ejemplo:

**index.php**

```
    <form class="form-group"  method="POST" action="mirandaenloscomentarios.com/busqueda/">

      <div class="input-group mb-3">

          <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..."  id="search" name="search">
        <button  type="submit" class="input-group-append">


      <span class="input-group-text fas fa-search"></span>
   </button>

  </div>
</form>
```

**busqueda.php**

```
<?php
    $search=$_POST["search"];//obtener valor input 


          $query=$con->query("SELECT
                  id, post_title, post_photo, post_content, fecha,tipo_noticia
                  FROM nacionales
                  WHERE post_title like '%$search%' or tipo_noticia like '%$search%'

    if($query->num_rows > 0){

          echo "Resultados para: ".'"'.$search.'"';

         while($row=$query->fetch_array()){ 

                 echo $row['post_title'];
              }

             }
            ?>
```

¿Alguna idea de que sucede aquí? resumí el código para un mejor entendimiento.
Gracias agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Comment: has probado colonadole ` COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` al final de la consulta

Comment: indicas esto: `no encuentra el título que tenga la palabra política`, serías tan amable de editar y colocar una muestra de los datos de entrada para poder revisar mejor

Comment: si que lo hice agregue COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci y fue peor nisiquiera arroja resultados

Comment: prueba tu consulta en workbench o el gestor que tengas para ver si es problema de la base de datos

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS` ejecuta esa consulta para ver el collation de la tabla

Comment: Hola, tal vez el problema sea por el cotejamiento con el que creaste la base de datos, puedes probar cambiarlo con `ALTER DATABASE nombre_de_la_bd DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: Como dice @the-breaker el problema debe ser por el cotejamiento de la BD. Intenta mostrar la consulta con el parámetro recibido en cada caso y ejecuta a mano, a ver qué resultados tienes. Y también muestra algo de datos como te ha pedido Aprendiz